# Using Maven to start a socket listener before running integration tests

Tags: maven, integration-testing, netty

I'm working on a multi-module project that includes a few different components as well as a sub-module of end-to-end (integration) tests. This multi-project includes a few webapps that can talk to each other, libraries, and a TCP "daemon"-like application (i.e., it listens on a socket for connections and then handles requests from clients) written in [Netty](http://netty.io/).

Currently, we use [appasembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) to package up this socket listener, allowing us to install the socket listener as a Windows service on Windows (i.e., our workstations) or a standard init.d service in Linux (our main testing/production environment).

I'm generally happy with this arrangement, but it has a few disadvantages: to run end-to-end tests my workstation, we have to package up this socket listener, run the service installer (if I haven't already), then restart the service. There's some similar complexity on Linux. In either case, I can't find a clean way build, (unit) test, package, deploy, then run end-to-end tests for this whole system all in one command. This is made even more difficult by our variety of environments: I *might* be able to get something working, but it would be very platform-dependent.

What I would prefer is if Maven could just start up this socket listener in the `pre-integration-test` phase, then run tests, then stop the listener when tests are done. This seems like it *should* be possible because the main class of this listener is just a `Runnable`, and I can do things like run it in Eclipse just by saying "Run as Java Application".

So is there a way to get Maven to just execute a class in a given build phase? How would I then get Maven to "tear down" the listener after tests have run?

Comment: Take a look at [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) ?

Comment: Yes, but I can't think of a very clean way to use it. I might be missing something obvious, but if I just have Maven execute the class, then control will not be returned to the caller (i.e., Maven) because the socket listener will just run indefinitely.